# Rounded Borders in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I round borders in SwiftUI?

I would assume this would work:

```
.cornerRadius(10)
.border(Color.white)
```

Tho it dose not work.

This is my workaround for now:

```
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(lineWidth: 1).foregroundColor(.white))
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

That's not a workaround, it's how you do it in SwiftUI. Two things:

- There used to be a `cornerRadius` modifier that became deprecated in... beta 4? beta 5? Yes, it's been a moving target.
- With a **great** amount of thanks to @kontiki ([blog post](https://swiftui-lab.com/view-extensions-for-better-code-readability/)), here's an extension that nicely returns what you want:

  ```
   extension View {
       public func addBorder<S>(_ content: S, width: CGFloat = 1, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> some View where S : ShapeStyle {
           let roundedRect = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
           return clipShape(roundedRect)
                .overlay(roundedRect.strokeBorder(content, lineWidth: width))
       }
   }
  ```

Usage:

```
.addBorder(Color.white, width: 1, cornerRadius: 10)
```

Comment: This only works if the background is white! Because this is just adding an overlay, the background color outside of the rounded corners are still visible.

Comment: @Zorayr I've edited the answer, if you call `clipShape` with the `RoundedRectangle` before calling `overlay`, the code works with any background color

Comment: @DávidPásztor, thanks. This was possibly the last answer I've given with regards to SwiftUI - and I noted the date of it, which was *before* it was out of beta. I'm so far out of touch, I wouldn't dare to edit my own answer. :-)

Comment: very nice. Works great

Answer (score 18):

Developers looking for **circular shape & border**.

```
Image("turtlerock")
   .clipShape(Circle())
   .overlay(
       Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
```

Answer (score 8):

For an **outside aligned rounded border**, before the overlay, you can add in some padding to the view ⤵︎

```swift
let strokeWidth: CGFloat = 1

YourView
    .padding([.all], strokeWidth / 2) // set the width to half of the stroke width
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
        .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: strokeWidth)
    )
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this one:

```
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0).stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: borderWidth))
.foregroundColor(.blue)
```

the overlay doesn't get along with the offset method...

Answer (score 2):

Because .cornerRadius() is deprecated in SwiftUI, here's how I did the example with the Button, in two ways.

First variant:

```
Button {
    print("Tapped")
} label: {
    Text("Name of a button")
        .frame(width: 280, height: 50)
        .background(Color.white)
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
 }
```

Second variant:

```
Button {
    print("Tapped")
} label: {
    Text("Name of a button")
        .frame(width: 280, height: 50)
        .background(Color.white)
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium))
        .clipShape(.buttonBorder)
 }
```

Comment: This is good and simple.